# Selecting from table with categories of people

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a database in ms sql , in the database I have three category of persons namely staff, customers, suppliers whom I stored in different tables create serial unique id for each.

Now these persons id are stored under person_id and a column names person type which stores whether its a staff, custimer or supplier in the transaction table, The problem lies in selecting the records from the transaction table like this pseudo code

```
Select t.*,s.na as staff,sp.name as supplier, c.name as customer
From Trans t 
left join Staff s on s.id = t.pid
left join Suppliers sp on sp.id = t.pid
left join Customers c on c.id = t.pid
```

This returns one row, instead of at least 3 or more, How do I solve this problem

My trans table

```
person_id    Person_type    Trans_id
1            staff            1
1            customer         2
2            customer         3
3            suppler          4
1            staff            5
```

Expected output

```
person_name      Trans_id
james            1
mark             2
dan              3
jude             4
james            5
```

Staff, Customers, and suppliers are stored in their different tables

Comment: Can you please supply sample data and desired results?

Comment: @sgeddes I added more info

Comment: Performing a left join on the Transaction tables returns ALL rows of that table. The pseudo-query you have supplied should do what you want. If it doesn't then there is sth missing in the description you gave us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what the Join does, combine data from multiple tables into one result row. If you want to "keep the rows", not combine them, you can use UNION

```
(
    Select t.* From Trans t 
    left join Staff s on s.id = t.pid
)
UNION
(
    Select t.* From Trans t 
    left join Suppliers sp on sp.id = t.pid
)
UNION
(
    Select t.* From Trans t 
    left join Customers c on c.id = t.pid    
)
```

This will get you the multiple rows you want BUT still not sure you have defined it right. I see you are only taking columns from Trans, so you're not getting any data from the other tables. And you're doing left outer joins so the other tables won't affect the selection. So I think it's just that same as selecting from just Trans.

If what you want is data from Trans where there is corresponding entry in the other tables, then do the UNION, but also change the outer joins to inner.

Comment: I am getting this error `All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.`

Comment: @Smith, my query as typed I don't think would give you that. So sounds like you've added columns form the other tables which is fine BUT the columns each UNIONed set has to have the same number of columns and types. Check if that's true and if not see if you can paste your SQL (maybe as "second try" in your question) and I'll take a look.

Comment: thanks i was ablr to make sure all columns outputed by each query have the same name